# javascript statement syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have a statement in my script like this:

```
if(some condition)
{
 false;
 //rest of code
}
```

I am not getting the meaning of the `false;` statement as standalone statement.

Comment: This seems strange. Could you show the exact code instead of a simplified one to see if there's some reason to it?

Comment: It appears to be a totally redundant statement, and will have absolutely no effect on the execution of the code.

Comment: false is a value, thus it has no effect. It is like writing `23` or `"hi"`...

Answer (score 1):

This statement is simply totally useless.

The whole code you show does nothing if `some condition` has no side effect.

It's probable somebody forgot something, like a `return`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either return the value from a function, or assign it to a variable.

For example:

```
function myFunction()
{
    if(some_condition)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or

```
var my_var;
if(some_condition)
{
    my_var = false;
}
```